# Какой тип данных правильно использовать как логический в C?

Tags: c

Какой тип данных правильно использовать как логический в C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если используется C99, то стоит задействовать его возможности, подключив заголовок `stdbool.h`. Например, так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BOOL(b) b ? "true" : "false"

void main() {
    bool t = true, f = false;

    printf("t = %s, f = %s\n", BOOL(t), BOOL(f));
}
```

Если C99 не используется, то предопределенного логического типа нет. Обычно используют макроопределения

```
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0
```

или перечисления

```
typedef enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1 } bool;
```

при этом используемым типом данных может быть любой подходящий целочисленный тип.

Comment: Собственно, если подключать stdbool.h, то все вопросы решаются. В C89 этот заголовок определяет макросы, а в C99 там встроенный тип _Bool тайпдефится как bool

Comment: Оставить как есть `int` и не мудрить. И не сравнивать на равенство.